# Updating global set from controller

Tags: plugin-development, controller, globals

This is my code:

```
$giveaway = Craft::$app->globals->getSetByHandle('promotions');
$giveaway->giveawayName = "New Name";
$success = Craft::$app->globals->saveSet($giveaway);
return($success);
```

Controller returns true, but no changes have been made to the "promotions" global set. What have I missed?

Comment: `saveSet` will save the Global's settings/fields. [See here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/GlobalsController.php#L228) to save content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oli’s comment is mostly right, but I think the solution is event simpler—the method you discovered is specifically for saving the `GlobalSet` settings/definition (like its name, handle, and the fields it uses), but what you're looking for is a more generic method for saving the `Element` that contains the actual content (as though you were updating it from the main *Globals* menu in the CP):

```php
// Generic save method for any Element type, including Globals:
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($giveaways);
```

✌️